# Json Data Model Advantages

Tags: ios

What are the actual advantages if you are using

- Json Data Model Classes

  in your application instead you can work without using it?

Answer (score 0):

1. More readable
2. Easy to handle common operations such as handling null fields.
3. If there's a change in JSON (changes in key fields) , you'll only have to worry about one place which is the Data Model Class. Otherwise you would have to go through each view controller and change the key fields.
4. You can add relevant data fetching methods to the model class, as class methods ,which is a good way to reduce coupling of your data access layer with your viewcontrollers.

Comment: Does it also improve the performance as well? If yes ,can you explain me the way? thanks